# Can we open pdf without using Google service

Tags: pdf, service, webview

I need to open a PDF in my project, and I'm using Web-view to load the PDF URL with google service. It is working in the old version, in the new version it is opening in an external window of google PDF reader.

```
webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + "http://cateringkitchen.in/" + file);
```

My code looks like the above. I want my PDF to open in web view not in an external app of Google.

Comment: You need a pdf library, some nice examples include MuPDF, pdf.js and if you won't mind, you can tweak the chromium base too. The webview can not display the pdf format without an appropriate renderer

Comment: okay, i also did this but i searched for this and i found that java 8 version will support this not lesser version. is it right?

Comment: It will be good news if it does, but personally I have always been satisfied with MuPDF as a native library for my applications

Comment: i will try it. thank you.

Comment: can we run direct URL of PDF